# Find sequence of sequences?

Tags: integer-sequence

There is a function `FindSequenceFunction` in Mathematica, that can identify a sequence of integers based on a few first elements. But what if I have a set of finite sequences `sec[n]` that grows with `n`? For example:

```
sec[0]={1}
sec[1]={1, 1}
sec[2]={1, 6, 1}
sec[3]={1, 15, 15, 1}
sec[4]={1, 28, 70, 28, 1}
sec[5]={1, 45, 210, 210, 45, 1}
sec[6]={1, 66, 495, 924, 495, 66, 1}
sec[7]={1, 91, 1001, 3003, 3003, 1001, 91, 1}
sec[8]={1, 120, 1820, 8008, 12870, 8008, 1820, 120, 1}
```

**Is there a way to use Mathematica to find the general expression to continue this sequence of sequences?**

Comment: I flattened this to a single sequence.  It is  https://oeis.org/A086645.  I haven't tried it in Mathematica yet, but flattening is probably a good first step.

Comment: More concisely: you have a (Riordan) triangle of integers that you want to identify. @mikado, that's when you're lucky and your triangle is listed in the OEIS. The question of how one might find a tentative formula for a given integer triangle is still an interesting one, tho.

Comment: Wow, this finding is amazing, thank you! Yes, still wondering if there is a way to proceed in a general case.

Comment: Looks like 1/2 of Pascal's Triangle

Comment: A simple idea is to use `FindSequenceFunction` on the columns of the triangular sequence. For example, `FindSequenceFunction[{1,6,15,28,45,66,91}]` and `FindSequenceFunction[{1,15,70,210,495,1001,1820}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindSequenceFunction` can find the each individual sequence `sec[k]` in terms of a recursion with polynomial coefficients:

```
FindSequenceFunction[PadRight[sec[5], 20]]
(*
  DifferenceRoot[
   Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {(-66 + 23 \[FormalN] - 
          2 \[FormalN]^2) \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + \[FormalN] (-1 + 
          2 \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 
      0, \[FormalY][1] == 1}]]
*)
```

Therefore, it can be used again to try to find the sequence of the coefficients as functions of `k`, which it can do in this case.

```
k0 = 3;
{y0coeff, y1coeff} = FindSequenceFunction /@ Transpose@
    Table[
     Normal@Last@CoefficientArrays[
        First[FindSequenceFunction@PadRight[sec[k], 20]][y, n] // 
         First,
        {y[n], y[1 + n]}],
     {k, k0 + 1, 8}] /. n -> #2
(*
{-28 + 15 #2 - 2 #2^2 - 15 #1 + 4 #2 #1 - 2 #1^2 &,
 #2 (-1 + 2 #2) &}
*)
```

The function `secFN[k, n]` can be used to generate `sec[k]`:

```
secFN = Function[{k, n},
   DifferenceRoot[
     Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]},
      {y0coeff[k - k0, \[FormalN]] \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + 
         y1coeff[k - k0, \[FormalN]] \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 0,
       \[FormalY][1] == 1}
      ]
     ][n + 1]
   ];
```

Example:

```
Table[secFN[5, n], {n, 0, 5}]
(*  {1, 45, 210, 210, 45, 1}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

How is this?

```
fx[x_, n_] := (x + 1)^n
f[n_] := Map[Part[fx[y, n] // ExpandAll, {#}] /. y -> 1 &, 
  Range[Length[fx[y, n] // ExpandAll]]]
Map[f[#] &, Range[2, 20, 2]]
(* Out: {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, {1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1}, {1, 8, 28, 56, 
  70, 56, 28, 8, 1}, {1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 
  1}, {1, 12, 66, 220, 495, 792, 924, 792, 495, 220, 66, 12, 1}, {1, 
  14, 91, 364, 1001, 2002, 3003, 3432, 3003, 2002, 1001, 364, 91, 14, 
  1}, .. *)

Map[#[[1 ;; ;; 2]] &, %]
(* Out: {{1, 1}, {1, 6, 1}, {1, 15, 15, 1}, {1, 28, 70, 28, 1}, {1, 45, 210, 
  210, 45, 1}, {1, 66, 495, 924, 495, 66, 1}, {1, 91, 1001, 3003, 
  3003, 1001, 91, 1}, {1, 120, 1820, 8008, 12870, 8008, 1820, 120, 
  1}, {1, 153, 3060, 18564, 43758, 43758, 18564, 3060, 153, 1}, {1, 
  190, 4845, 38760, 125970, 184756, 125970, 38760, 4845, 190, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Note that the formula `Binomial[2 n, 2 k]` is given in the OEIS link.